# What's the advantage to define some function out of class in python program

Tags: python, class, function

Why should functions be declared outside of the class they're used in in Python?

For example, the [following project on Github](https://github.com/sjl/t/blob/master/t.py) does this with its `_hash`, `_task_from_taskline`, and `_tasklines_from_tasks` functions. The format is the same as the following:

```
class UnknownPrefix(Exception):
"""Raised when trying to use a prefix that does not match any tasks."""
def __init__(self, prefix):
    super(UnknownPrefix, self).__init__()
    self.prefix = prefix


def _hash(text):

    return hashlib.sha1(text).hexdigest()

def _task_from_taskline(taskline):
    """
    snipped out actual code
    """
    return task

def _tasklines_from_tasks(tasks):
    """Parse a list of tasks into tasklines suitable for writing."""


    return tasklines
```

But I think these functions have a relation with the class `TaskDict`.

Why put them out of the class? What is the advantage of having them declared outside of the class?

Comment: Turn it around: What would the advantage be to put them in the class instead?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Encapsulation.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: what if the functions have no bearing on the instance state?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Then I'd put them in another file, or put them somewhere they'd make sense. It's the C# developer in me.  The weird thing for me is just seeing functions hanging off nowhere, making it hard to determine what part of the system they deal with.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: Right. But Python is a little more flexible. You'll often find private helper functions bundled in the same module; that's where they are used, but they don't operate on the state of the classes, so they are defined as separate functions outside of the class. That keeps the classes themselves uncluttered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Stop Writing Classes](http://pyvideo.org/video/880/stop-writing-classes) PyCon talk is not exactly on this subject but includes what I feel are related lessons here: basically, the idea is that *classes are for creating objects*.  All of the attributes, instance methods and class methods should further the goal of creating objects or making the objects work.  Classes are not for code organization (under this theory) -- that's what modules are for.

This is a very opinionated strategy and not everyone agrees with it.  But if you think about your example in this context, it's clear that the reason the functions aren't part of the class is that even though the functions are used by the class, they don't actually operate on any object or further the creation of any object directly.  They're just utility functions that aren't bound to any specific class, and could theoretically be used elsewhere in the library.

So why or why not put them in the class?  It boils down to whether you believe that classes should be used for code organization or not.  In this case, the author apparently bought into the idea that it's modules that are for code organization, not classes.

Answer (score 3):

1. They are easier to import and have shorter name than member functions
2. Even if you put them in the class, they're probably going to be a classmethod/staticmethod anyway.
3. Pythonic code uses duck-typing; a method would imply that it can only be used with that class, while in fact the code may be more generic than that.
4. Personal preference. Some people liked to separate between the "domain model" and the "business logic".

In the end, for this particular program, there is really no benefit nor disadvantage for doing either way.

Comment: Yes, to me. I will put them in the class and define as staticmethod.

Answer (score 3):

functions has small performance advantage

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.Timer('foo()', 'def foo(): return 1').timeit()
0.09944701194763184
>>> timeit.Timer('A.foo()', '''
... class A(object):
...     @staticmethod
...     def foo():
...         return 1''').timeit()
0.12048101425170898
```

Answer (score 1):

If the functions defined all operate on data within the object, it would only make sense to encapsulate the functions to the class level.  Also, seeing how the class is the only thing calling those functions, it would make sense to put these in the class.

The only advantage of putting them outside the class is if you have other code that will use these functions that are unrelated to the class itself.  Or if you are building some helper functions that will be used by other modules.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, when deciding where to put functions it is important to recognize what is going to use the functions. If they are internal to the class and wont be used by other parts of your program it makes sense to put them in the class. But if other parts will most likely use them, they should be at the module level.

Comment: yes, I have thought that, I think the functions is belong to the class, and won't be used bu others out of the class. So I doubt why define out of class